# XMPP background traffic analysis

Tags: xmpp

I am running a Jabber client (which has only bots in its buddy list) in the system tray. I don't run it in the foreground, it just stays in the minimized state. Since there is no active communication, I assume the only traffic generated will be because of presence updates (after the initial setup with the server, please correct me if I am wrong). Since, the presence updates are push-based and the bots and my client are always available, I should see no traffic after some time, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server can (and likely will) send periodic "ping" messages to your client to see if you are still there.  Go run Miranda IM client and open the XML console to see what the client and server send to each other.

About once a minute, my OpenFire server and Miranda client have this little exchange.

```
<!-- SERVER SENDS -->
<iq type="get" id="mir_8">
    <ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping" />
</iq>
```

­

```
 <!-- CLIENT SENDS BACK -->
<iq type="result" id="mir_8" to="testaccount1@foobar.com/Miranda" />
```

GTalk server does the same thing.  My openfire server can be configured to disable pings.  I imagine other servers can to.

Comment: Many clients and servers also send a space character periodically to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I have found on android at least, if you turn off the pings by the openfire server, the client will generate white space messages once every 30 seconds